# Will clearInterval stop queued interval execution

Tags: javascript, clearinterval

Let's say I have these this

```
myInterval=setInterval(funcA,50);

function funcA(){
  //Some code that takes longer than 50ms to run
}

setTimeout(function(){clearInterval(myInterval);},10000}
```

Let's say funcA always takes longer than 50ms to make it simple. Naturally, many funcA runs will pile up and be queued. Will clearInterval **remove those queued runs** or just **stop** queuing new ones?

I did make a fiddle to test it, and it turns out clearInterval stops all future execution, even those that have already be queued. I just need to confirm this behavior is consistent (across browsers/platforms).

```js
var myInterval=setInterval(funcA,20);

setTimeout(function(){
  clearInterval(myInterval);
  
  console.log('Clearing interval at ' + Date.now());
  
},400);

var lastRunTimeStamp=0;

function funcA(){
  while(Date.now()<lastRunTimeStamp+25){}
  lastRunTimeStamp=Date.now();
  console.log('Run at ' + lastRunTimeStamp);
}
```

--Update--

The queued execution assumption in this question is incorrect, please check T.J. Crowder answer for an explanation.

Comment: Bonus question: any idea why this behavior is not clearly documented (at least where I looked)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Naturally, many `funcA` runs will pile up and be queued.

No, they won't, because of the way the repeated timer works. Timer behavior in browsers is (now) specified by the [WHAT-WG "HTML5" specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#timers). Queuing the next task is done as *part* of the previous task, after your callback has completed, not separately from it; [details here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#timer-initialisation-steps). So there will only be *one* outstanding task at a time (after it's been queued, before the JavaScript engine can pick it up and work on it).

> Will `clearInterval` remove those queued runs or just stop queuing new ones?

No*, but it doesn't have to. The first step in the task queued by the timer system is to see if the timer is still on the list of active timers; if it isn't, [the task terminates](http://If%20the%20entry%20for%20handle%20in%20the%20list%20of%20active%20timers%20has%20been%20cleared,%20then%20abort%20this%20task%27s%20substeps.) before calling your callback. So it's *as though* `clearInterval` removed the task (e.g., your formerly-queued callback doesn't get run), but not because `clearInterval` cleared it (instead, it's because the task checked).

It's easy to test and prove the behavior: Just schedule a timer, then busy-wait for longer than its interval, then clear it:

```js
var counter = 0;
var timer = setInterval(function() {
  ++counter;
  console.log("timer fired:", counter);
  if (counter == 1) {
    setTimeout(busyWaitAndClear, 0);
  }
}, 500); // Every 500ms
function busyWaitAndClear() { // Obviously never really do this
  var done = Date.now() + 1000;
  while (done > Date.now()) {
    // wait
  }
  clearInterval(timer);
  console.log("timer cleared");
}
```

Note that the timer only fires once, and doesn't fire a second time even though presumably at least one task to fire it was queued while we busy-waited.

---

* ("No" - The [description of `clearInterval`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#dom-clearinterval) doesn't say anything about reading into the pending tasks list and removing tasks queued by the interval but not yet picked up.)

Comment: Interesting. What's the procedure here (for a question based on a wrong premise)? Should I fix it somehow, or even remove it?

Comment: @RSinohara: Others may well also have the wrong assumption, so I'd say leave it as-is. (Also, changing questions such that they invalidate existing answers is pretty frowned-upon on SO.)

Comment: @RSinohara: FWIW, I've also corrected an error in the answer and added some detail as well as a way to test.

Comment: Very interesting, putting the clearInterval inside the callback is the key to the proof. Very nice.

Comment: Do you have any data on browsers that do not implement this standard though?

Comment: @RSinohara: Not really. `var timer = setInterval(...); busyWaitForTooLong(); clearInterval(timer);` demonstrates it as well.

Comment: @RSinohara: No. Current Chrome and Firefox, and IE11, all work as advertised (I checked them with the snippet above). :-) I don't have a copy of Edge handy right now.